# Google Sheets - Parse one cell to find text from another (then mark as TRUE or FALSE)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm working on a sheet where I have a list of vendor names in column A and website URLs in column B.

I would like to add conditional formatting to column B to highlight green or red if the website URL does or does not contain the vendor name.

Right now, I have this working through multiple cells.

`A          B          C          D
AOL        AOL.com    TRUE       1`

First, I have a cell with the formula `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1, B1))`
Then I convert this to a number `=if(C1=true,1,0)` and base the conditional formatting for column B on `D1=1`.

This works great, except column B needs to be a direct match, where I would like to make it so column C marks as true based on finding the text regardless of formatting.

Example that currently does not work as I would like:

`A                    B               C          D
1 800 Contacts  1800contacts.com    FALSE        0`

Is there a way I can change the `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1, B1))` formula so that both of these examples would be marked as TRUE?

Thank you

Comment: You could remove spaces by using: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""), B1))`

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad, that did exactly what I wanted it to. I've been trying different functions, but the simple answer worked the best! 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove spaces by using:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""), B1))
```